# Comparing 2 values stored in the symbolic parameters in jcl

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I need to compare the values stored in 2 symbolic parameters.

For example

```
Set1 set day1=&odd
Set2 set day2=&cdd
```

What I need to do is if the values of day1 and day2 are equal, then execute a specific action else execute different set of codes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. This sounds a little like an X-Y problem. Can you explain what different actions you want to take? How is the JCL constructed? Why not just construct the JCL differently if the 2 parameters are the same. You may have a valid use case, but in 35 years I've never seen the need to do this.

Comment: You cannot compare the value of JCL symbolic parameters with JCL. The JCL `IF` statement only supports testing step return codes, and ABEND codes. You could pass both values to, e.g. a REXX routine, compare in the REXX, and set different return codes to then use JCL `IF` statements to choose which steps to execute.

Comment: Where are the values for &odd and &cdd coming from? Are they IWS variables?

Comment: Thanks everyone for such valuable suggestions and replies...

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish your goal is to write each symbolic parameter to a temporary file with your SORT product, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21497642/624463).  Now that you have two files, you can compare them with IEBCOMPR and if they are equal then the parameters were equal.  You can use a JCL IF statement to test the return code from IEBCOMPR.